# Cannot unselect list field as required

Tags: 2013

I want to make a field non-required in a new form. I'm going to list settings and click on a field, then switch the radio button next to `This column must contain information` from `Yes` to `No`. I click OK and it lookes like it's done... except it's not. When I go to form it's still required and when I go to list settings one more time the field `This column must contain information` is still checked as `Yes`. What's also interesting is that I can change the field's name or description without problem.

Does anybody is familiar with that issue? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to change the column in the content type instead. Go to list settings > advanced settings > "allow management of content types" to Yes. Click OK, and the content type will be available above the list columns. Click the content type and here you will find all the columns. Click the one column you wish to set to not required and set it to "Optional ( may contain information)".

Comment: @user19952 The thing is that this column doesn't show up on this list. There are all of them except this one. Does it matter it's a lookup field?

Comment: That do sounds weird. I just tried to create a lookup column and set it to required. I could change it after to not be required. The same with the content type, the lookup column did show up here, and i could set it to optional.. Sounds to me that the column is not working as it should. Can you access the site with SharePoint Designer and go to the list and see if all the columns is there? There is an option to show all hidden columns and set them to required/optional from there.

Comment: @user19952 Yes! That helped! Thank you! Changing this property in SharePoint Designer was the solution. Could you please add it as answer so I could mark it as accepted in next 48 hours?

Comment: Glad it worked out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the column in the content type instead.

Go to list settings > advanced settings > "allow management of content types" to Yes.

Click OK, and the content type will be available above the list columns. Click the content type and here you will find all the columns. 
Click the one column you wish to set to not required and set it to "Optional (may contain information)"

If that option does not work out, try instead to access the site with SharePoint Designer and go to the specific list and see if all the columns is there?

There is an option to show all hidden columns and set them to required/optional from here.